# Copying values from formulas VBA, get zeros

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a quite big project in VBA and I need to copy some values  (without formulas) from one workbook to another. These values were evaluated earlier with FormulaR1C1 method (Actually there are multiple source workbooks, I open them inside the for loop and copy data to NewWb)
I tried following code:

```
Sub CopyAndPaste()
Range("U4").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Range("U4").FormulaR1C1 = "=If(R8C9 < 1, 0, 0.03)"

       
Range("V4").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Range("V4").FormulaR1C1 = "=If(R9C9 < 1, 0, 0.03)"


'''Here follows some other formula stuff like that

   Dim ReportWb As Workbook
   Dim ReportWs As Worksheet
   Workbooks.Add.SaveAs "\Path\NewWb.xlsx"
   Set ReportWb = Workbooks("NewWb.xlsx")
   Set ReportWs = ReportWb.Sheets(1)
   
For Each wb in Dir ' It's abstract loop, I copy one row to ReportWb from each file
   wb.Open
   If ReportWs.Range("A1") = "" Then
       wb.Sheets(1).Range("L3:Y3").Copy ' Here I copy header with formatting, this works fine
       ReportWs.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
   End If

'Here I search for the last row of destination worksheet and try to paste a row to destination worksheet, but get only zeros 

   LastRowReport = ReportWs.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   wb.Sheets(1).Range("U4:V4").Copy
   ReportWs.Cells(LastRowReport + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   ReportWs.Cells(LastRowReport + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Next wb

End Sub
```

I've also tried proceed that this way

```
ReportWs.Range(Cells(LastRowReport + 1, 1).Address, Cells(LastRowReport + 1, 14).Address).Value2 = wb.Sheets(1).Range("U4:V4").Value2
```

But I still get 0 instead of actual values.

Obviously formulas can't be evaluated and copied inside one sub simultaneously or rather successively, values are copied before formula evaluation for a reason. But I still have no idea how to solve my problem.

Would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Please, try starting your code with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`. If it is set on `xlCalculationManual`, the entered formula will not be evaluated.

Comment: Probably not your issue, but the first 4 lines should have workbook and worksheet references. Are you saying the formulas evaluate to something other than zero but when you copy them they become zero?

Comment: @FaneDuru Unfortunately Calculation doesn't help. I've also tried to force the specific worksheet  to evaluate using ReportWs.Evaluate, no effect.

Comment: @SJR, Yes, I apologize, I may have taken not enough info from my project, that's actually a problem piece of code. All Formulas take place on an Activesheet, it was specified earlier. Activesheet is also an iterator in a For Each loop